Show that this function is integrable.
Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1 & \text { si } x \in S \\ 0 & \text { si } x \notin S\end{array}\right.$ where $S=\left\{\frac{1}{n} \in \mathbb{N}\right\} $.
Show that $f \in R[0,1]$ and
$$
\int_0^1 f(x) d x=0
$$
i tried to do this,
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary.
Consider the set $S=\left\{\left.\frac{1}{n} \right\rvert\, n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$, which consists of isolated points in the interval $[0,1]$. Let $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$.
Define a partition $P=\left\{x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n\right\}$ of $[0,1]$ such that:

$x_0=0$ and $x_n=1$.
For each $i=1,2, \ldots, n-1$, let $x_i=\frac{1}{m_i}$, where $m_i$ is the smallest natural number such that $\frac{1}{m_i}>\delta$.

Now, consider the upper and lower Riemann sums $U(P, f)$ and $L(P, f)$ associated with this partition $P$.
For any subinterval $\left[x_{i-1}, x_i\right]$, if $x_i$ contains a point in $S$, then $M_i=1$ and $m_i=0$. Otherwise, $M_i=0$ and $m_i=0$.
Therefore, both the upper and lower Riemann sums are equal to zero for this partition $P$, since all subintervals either contain a point in $S$ or do not.
Hence, for any $\varepsilon>0$, we have constructed a partition $P$ such that $U(P, f)-L(P, f)=$ $0<\varepsilon$.
Therefore $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, and $\int_0^1 f(x) d x=0$.

What is your question?

i tried that but i'm not sure if is correct or not, my question is if that is correct or what is the correct proof of there exercise.

Please update your post with some information about what parts you are unsure of, or parts of your proof that you would like for users to help verify

i'm not sure with the $x_i$ and the upper and lower sum

Please edit your post to reflect this.

what do you mean edit?, write where i have questions?

There should be an "edit" button at the bottom of your post. You can click it then change the text in your post to add or modify it.

i tried but i don't know what you mean for edit, mi question is if the proof is correct or no and why?
